# how to run giix extension in yii

Tags: php, yii

I use the following url to run gii: `localhost/path to index.php?r=gii`, but only gii module runs not giix.

please tell me the correct configuration for giix?

my config.php is :

```
'import'=>array(
    'application.models.*',
    'application.components.*',
),
'gii' => array(
    'class' => 'system.gii.GiiModule',
    'password'=>'.......',
    'generatorPaths' => array(
        'ext.giix.generators', // giix generators
    ),
),
'components'=>array(
    'ext.giix.components.*', 
    'messages' => array ( // giix messages directory,giix is  and extension.
        'extensionBasePaths' => array(
            'ext.giix.messages', // giix messages directory.
        ),
    ),
),
```

Comment: Do you choose generators? Giix add new generator's not clearly module

Comment: @Sergery,i could not well understand..plz help me in detail .i m newbie so your coperation will be highly obliged.thanks

Comment: When you go to localhost/path/index.php?r=gii - and you may choose generator's path

Answer (score 3):

According to the Giix documentation you need to import the **'ext.giix-components.*'** and the generatorPaths should be **'ext.giix-core'**.   So your code should look like:

```
 'import'=>array(
        'application.models.*',
        'application.components.*',
        'ext.giix-components.*', // You need to import the giix component
    ),
    'gii' => array(
        'class' => 'system.gii.GiiModule',
        'password'=>'.......',
        'generatorPaths' => array(
            'ext.giix-core', // giix generator
        ),
    ),
```